# React Native Statusbar wrong color

Tags: react-native, statusbar

I have a react native app with multiple screens. Each component has its own statusbar to define its color (see code ex component). When starting the app the right color is shown but when I go to a screen which uses another color (black instead of white or vice versa) it changes correctly but afterwards it won't change anymore when navigating further. It seems like the color can be changed only once.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={theme.container}>
      <StatusBar
        translucent={false}
        backgroundColor={S.COLOR_STATUS_BAR_DARK}
        barStyle="dark-content"
      />
      {this.props.isFetching || this.props.isSubmitting
        ? <Spinner />
        :
        <View style={theme.container}>
          { this.renderAlarms() }
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your component is not re-render.
**A** ---> **B**
When A render. Statusbar color: red
When B render. Statusbar color: blue
Back to A. A is not re-render. Statusbar color: blue,

if A component **re-render**, this problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

Re-rendering the component did the trick indeed. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If this is right solution then mark an answer as correct (the green check image) and upvote my comment if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change color of your Status with static [setBackgroundColor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#setbackgroundcolor) function.

I will recommend to set your status color on `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to set back to previous status color as shown in following example.

```
componentDidMount() {
  StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('red');
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('white');
}
```